# Renew DHCP from the command line on a Mac

Tags: macos, network

Can I run command `sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP` as a standard user which **shouldn't** prompt for administrative username and password?

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo ipconfig set $if DHCP && echo OK
```

Where `$if` is your network interface. For example `en0`.

To find which interface you want to reset, you can see the output of `ifconfig`.

Or if you are lazy, you can just copy/paste this line, which will set `$if` to the interface which is used to access the Internet:

```
if=$(route -n get 0.0.0.0 2>/dev/null | awk '/interface: / {print $2}') && echo $if
```

So in the right order:

```
if=$(route -n get 0.0.0.0 2>/dev/null | awk '/interface: / {print $2}') && echo $if
sudo ipconfig set $if DHCP && echo OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The Network Command Cheat Sheet at [Krypted.com](http://krypted.com/mac-security/mac-network-commands-cheat-sheet/) has this example:

> Set the interface called Wi-Fi to obtain it if it isn’t already
>
> `networksetup -setdhcp Wi-Fi`

You need to replace Wi-Fi with the interface name bound to en0.

Answer (score 0):

(I just realized, years later, that my previous "answer" actually wasn't an answer to the real question at all.)

The real question seems to be "How to run a command which requires `sudo` without needing to enter a password?".

The solution is to use the `NOPASSWD:` option in the sudoers file, followed by the command for which you want to suppress the password prompt.

Do NOT use `NOPASSWD: ALL` as suggested in many examples, but specify the command(s) which will not require a password.

Also, the `/private/etc/sudoers` file in MacOS seems to be overwritten on updates. So instead, create a file in `/private/etc/sudoers.d/`.

So in your case, for the `ipconfig` command, using `visudo` to create a file:

```
# Make visudo use nano rather than vi
export VISUAL=nano

sudo visudo -f /private/etc/sudoers.d/nopasswd
```

In the file, use this line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ipconfig
```